# Docker Service updatedAt timestamp

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-api, docker-swarm-mode

Docker Swarm API client has the following meta information for a service:

```
Meta.UpdatedAt
```

Is this the timestamp of last user-initiated `update` (e.g. change service configuration) OR is it a timestamp of *any* change on service, that even Docker Swarm performs?

For example, if my swarm service has 5 tasks spread across cluster, and then Docker for some reason move one task from one node to another node (so the service configuration is NOT changed); would it update this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: No this won't.

If you look at the source code, `meta.UpdatedAt` is changed through the `touchMeta` method that is called by `update`. For a service, the method handling this is `UpdateService`, which is linked to the `docker service update` cli command. So technically, `meta.UpdatedAt` is updated only when you use `docker service update`.

You can test this quickly by following this scenario on your local machine or cluster:

```
$ docker service create --name redis --replicas 5 redis

$ docker service inspect --format='{{.Meta.UpdatedAt}}' redis
2017-01-07 15:16:14.910287822 +0000 UTC

$ docker rm -f <some-redis-task-id>

# Swarm should re-schedule the forced removed task onto another node

$ docker service inspect --format='{{.Meta.UpdatedAt}}' redis
2017-01-07 15:16:14.910287822 +0000 UTC
```

The `meta.UpdatedAt` field should be left unchanged.

Now call `docker service update redis --replicas 10` and you should see the new timestamp.

Comment: Thank you, this is an awesome answer!